# Split in half vertically and horizontally second flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can please someone point me out how can I split out second flex item vertically and horizontally like I have in image below ?

I managed to split in half one big box but I failed making it the same for second flex item.
This is what I have right now -> https://jsfiddle.net/paveu/8c9Ls5s8/

Thanks,

HTML

```
<div class="desktop">
  <div class="yellow">lorem</div>
  <div class="orange">lorem</div>
  <div class="purple">lorem</div>
  <div class="green">lorem</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main,
div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.desktop {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;

}

.desktop > div {
  flex: 1;
}

div.orange {
  background-color: #FFAD77;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div.yellow {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #FFE377;
}

div.purple {
  width: 30%;
    margin-left: 10px;

  background-color: #FF77C8;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop > div {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  div.orange {
    order: -1;
    flex: 2;
  }
  div.yellow {
    flex: 5;
  }
  div.purple {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

[image: End result for flexbox]

Comment: `I managed to split in half one big box but I failed making it the same for second flex item.` ??

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I only managed to split window in half to have yellow and left side and orange nad purple on right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this tell me if there is a problem in my answer

**html:**

```
<div class="desktop">
  <div class="yellow">lorem</div>
  <div class="orange">lorem</div>
  <div class="purple">lorem</div>
  <div class="green">lorem</div>

</div>
```

**css:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main,
div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.desktop {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}

div.orange {
  background-color: #FFAD77;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

div.yellow {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #FFE377;
}

div.purple {
    flex: 0 0 50%;

  width: 30%;
  background-color: #FF77C8;
}
div.green{
  background-color: green;
  width:30%;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop div {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div[orange] {
    order: -1;
    flex: 2;
  }
  div[yellow] {
    flex: 5;
  }
  div[purple] {
    flex: 1;
  }
  div[purple] {
    flex: 6;
  }
}
```

**output:**
[image]

Comment: There is no problem. You did a great job, thank you.

Comment: glad to help you