# Getting correct grid with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Can someone point me out how can I get a grid with Flexbox that is similar to the picture below. I have green column already done but have problem doing red section.

The problem is that I need to have an access to Flex Order just  re-order it on mobile resolutions.

What I have already:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paveu/8c9Ls5s8/76/)

**HTML**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main,
div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.desktop {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.desktop div {
  flex: 1;
}

div.orange {
  background-color: #FFAD77;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

div.yellow {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #FFE377;
}

div.purple {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #FF77C8;
}

div.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 30%;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop div {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.orange {
    order: 1;
  }
  div.yellow {
    order: 2;
  }
  div.purple {
    order: 3;
  }
  div.green {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <div class="yellow">lorem1</div>
  <div class="orange">lorem2</div>
  <div class="purple">lorem3</div>
  <div class="green">lorem4</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: so you asked for the first layout here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550792/split-in-half-vertically-and-horizontally-second-flex-item ... you got your answer, now you took the same code to ask for more.. and so on ... a clever way to have the whole project done step by step

Comment: I spent two days figuring out how to break the column to in order to make new flex items but I failed this is why I ask for help, sorry if it is wrong way for asking for help.

Comment: so my advice is to spent 2h reading a full tutorial about flexbox and understand each property and how things work, then you will easily do this ... you are free to ask, it's not my website and my comment worth nothing, but for me it's not the correct way to learn ... you will get a bunch of working code but you will have to understand the basics.

Comment: You're asking about flex order, but how are we supposed to know what color goes where if all the boxes in your image are red?

Comment: it doesn't matter you could pick your color, the thing is that all boxes must be within display flex if they are we can use flex order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please adjust the width, remove border and other things are per your requirement.

```css
.redouter {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.one {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.two {
  border: 5px solid white;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.three {
  min-height: 144px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.four {
  min-height: 10px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .redouter {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .red {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .one {
    order: 1;
  }
  .two {
    order: 2;
  }
  .three {
    order: 3;
  }
  .four {
    order: 2;
  }
}

.desktop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.yellow,
.green,
.purple,
.orange {
  flex: 1;
}

div.orange {
  background-color: #FFAD77;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

div.yellow {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #FFE377;
}

div.purple {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #FF77C8;
}

div.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 30%;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop div {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div[orange] {
    order: -1;
    flex: 2;
  }
  div[yellow] {
    flex: 5;
  }
  div[purple] {
    flex: 1;
  }
  div[purple] {
    flex: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <div class="yellow">lorem 1</div>
  <div class="orange">lorem 2</div>
  <div class="purple">lorem 3</div>
  <div class="green">lorem 4</div>
</div>

<div class="redouter">
  <div class="red one">1</div>
  <div class="red two">2</div>
  <div class="red three">3</div>
  <div class="red four">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow you're fast, thank you. just out of the scope. Is there possible to merge those two column layout green and red, just to use flex order on both together ? or it's not possible in flexbox.

Comment: That's not easy, it's not impossible though. Need to add several custom CSS to it. But still it's possible.